# Implementing bag of word algorithm from opencv sample codes

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to implement bagofwords_classification.cpp from opencv version 2.4.5 sample codes.cpp . What are the changes that we are required to make in this .cpp file for proper working of code. I am new to opencv and still trying sample codes.
How and where to add the Feature detector,descriptor extractor, descriptor matcher ?? in that .cpp code

Whenever i debug any code it never display results but just output the info about what that  .cpp file is gonna do. In (EXAMPLE) matching_to_many_images.cpp even the images are saved in the file but still no results are shown.

Answer (score 0):

To show an image, you can use cvShowImage("Title",image)  or imshow(). This depends on wheter to image is an IplImage or Mat.

The code example is not 'false', the program uses commandline arguments, thus to start it you need to add certain commands.

From the code

```
[feature detector]     
Feature detector name (e.g. SURF, FAST...) - see createFeatureDetector() function.

[descriptor extractor] 
Descriptor extractor name (e.g. SURF, SIFT) - see createDescriptorExtractor() function.

[descriptor matcher]   
Descriptor matcher name (e.g. BruteForce) - see createDescriptorMatcher() function.
```

then from those arguments it calls

```
Ptr<FeatureDetector> featureDetector = createFeatureDetector( ddmParams.detectorType );
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> descExtractor = createDescriptorExtractor(     ddmParams.descriptorType );
```